# Using MAX as a measure only on one column

Tags: max, powerbi, dax, measure

I have a table with thes headders;
Id  ProcessName CurrentStatus   Result  ProcessOwner    ProcessObjectCount  ProcessObjectCurrentItem    Errors  RunBy   HostSystem  ConnectedWithAccount    Step    OData__DCDateModified   Notes   ID.1    Date    ErrorCount  HasErrors

I want to use MAX on OData__DCDateModified so i get the latest list of the ProcessName.
I add ProcessName in to a table, create a mesure for MAX('TABLENAME'[OData__DCDateModified]) ant it works but when i add ID or any other value in that i want displayed the MAX stops working as I hoped.

Any thoughs?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get the MAX `OData__DCDateModified` for each `ProcessName`, ignoring any other filter contexts. In order to do this you need to use CALCULATE combined with ALLEXCEPT.

```
MaxProcess = CALCULATE(MAX(TABLENAME[OData__DCDateModified]),ALLEXCEPT(TABLENAME,TABLENAME[ProcessName]))
```

When you pass `ALLEXCEPT(TABLENAME,TABLENAME[ProcessName])` to CALCULATE, you are telling the formula to ignore every other filter context **except** the context on `ProcessName`

Comment: Hi Stu, thank you for your advice. I just tried that and as soon as I added the ID in to the table the measure displays all IDs too.

Comment: Hmmm your data may be structured differently than I thought.Can you edit your question to show a sample of your table along with a sample of what you want the output to be?